# Using sscanf to extract integers from strings without spaces

Tags: c, scanf

Is it possible to use **only** `sscanf` to extract the numbers from a strings without spaces? (I **have** to use **only** `sscanf` and no other function of `C`, because my code is [Neuron](http://www.neuron.yale.edu/neuron/static/docs/help/neuron/general/function/sscanf.html#sscanf) and it use only `sscanf`).

For example : `string = "Hello[9]five[22]"` or `string = "asdas[9]asda[22]"`
I do not know what are the strings, all I know that there are two numbers surrounded by brackets.

And I want to extract the integers with `sscanf`... is it possible?

Comment: unfortunately, it is. why not use `strchr()` and `strtol()` instead?

Comment: @H2CO3 I have to use sscanf ( I write the code in Neuron and it use sscanf only)

Comment: @mbratch the strings are not always the same strings... All I know that there are two numbers surrounded by []

Comment: @user2236185 Is [this](http://www.echelon.com/support/documentation/manuals/devtools/078-0002-02H_Neuron_C_Programmers_Guide.pdf) what you are working with?

Comment: @H2CO3 no I am talking about this : http://www.neuron.yale.edu/neuron/static/docs/help/neuron/general/function/sscanf.html#sscanf

Comment: `sscanf(string, "%*[^[][%d]%*[^[][%d]", &n1, &n2);`

Answer (score 2):

```
Be sure to check the return value of `sscanf()`

#define StringJunk "%*[^0-9[]"
// Any string that does _not_ contain digits nor '['. 
// '*' implies don't save the result.

const char *str = "Hello[9]five[22]"
int num[2];
int cnt =  sscanf(str, StringJunk "[%d]" StringJunk "[%d]", &num[0], &num[1]);

if (cnt == 2) Success();
else if (cnt == EOF) EndOfFileOccurred();
else ScanningError();
```

---

A pedantic check would use a sentinel to check for trailing junk.  Various methods exist.

```
int i = 0;
int cnt = sscanf(str, " " StringJunk "[%d]" StringJunk "[%d] %n", 
    &num[0], &num[1], &i);
if (cnt == 2 && str[i] == '\0') Success();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *test = "Hello[9]five[22]";
    const char *p;
    int num = 0;
    int spos1, spos2;

    if(argc>1)
        test = argv[1];

    p = test;
    while( *p ) {
        spos1 = spos2 = 0;
        if( sscanf(p, "%*[^[][%n%d]%n", &spos1, &num, &spos2) == 1) {
            printf("Found the number %d\n", num);
        }
        if( spos1 == 0 )
            p += 1;
        if( spos2 ) {
            p += spos2;
        } else {
            printf("Malformed number: no closing bracket.\n");
            p += spos1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor: If given the string `"Hello[9"`, I think code has an  infinite loop.   A missing `]` will stop the scan and leave `spos` at 0.

Comment: @chux: You are correct! I will need to fix that. Maybe moving the %n to just after the %d. I will look at it later.